# A hyphen is not displayed in chemfig

Tags: hyphenation, chemfig

I have a problem with a hyphen that is not displayed (according to my pdf file) in a chemical structure (after the arrow, {n}-Bu_4N^+)=-=)), although it is present in the code. My sample code is below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,doublespacing,letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage{chemfig}


\begin{document}


\setatomsep{2em}
setbondoffset{1pt}
\setdoublesep{3pt}
setbondstyle{line width=1pt}


\schemestart[0,2.2,thick]
\scriptsize
\chemfig{[:-30]*6(-=-(-[,1.2]BF{_3^-}K^+)=-=)}
\arrow{
->[\footnotesize \emph{n}-Bu$_4$N$^+$Br$^-$
\footnotesize][\footnotesize{\centering THF, rt, 3-5 min\footnotesize}]}
\scriptsize
\chemfig{[:-30]*6(-=-(-[,1.2]BF{_3^-}\emph{n}-Bu_4N^+)=-=)}
\schemestop


\end{document}
```

There is a hyphen in the structure that is above the arrow and it is diplayed without problems. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There are several problems with your MWE that mean I can't run it without changing it a bit. But I *think* all you need to do is to put the hyphen inside the scope of the `\emph`.  Try `\emph{n-}` instead of `\emph{n}-`.  Is that what you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-` is interpreted as a single bond. It seems as if it vanishes because the width of the “atom” `BF{_3^-}\emph{n}` is so big. You actually don't want the hyphen to be parsed as a bond so you need to hide it.

In the comments it was proposed to use `\emph{n-}` which works as it hides the hyphen from `chemfig`'s parser. I have another suggestion: since the atoms in `chemfig`'s formulas are set in math mode you could use [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\text{}`. Simply using `{-}` would also hide the dash but it would be interpreted as a minus then.

Below I also defined the command `\normal` for typesetting the *n* as this seems more natural to me. Also, I used `3--5\,min` for the time range. Personally I'd prefer using the [`siunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package and using `\SIrange{3}{5}{\minute}`. With appropriate settings (`\sisetup{range-phrase=--,range-units=single}`) the output would be the same.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% gloabel settings should go into the preamble:
\setatomsep{2em}
\setbondoffset{1pt}
\setdoublesep{3pt}
\setbondstyle{line width=1pt}

% a semantic command:
\newcommand\normal{\textit{n}}

\begin{document}

% if these are scheme-specific they're fine here; else they also should go
% into the preamble
\setarrowdefault{0,2.2,thick}% if it is scheme-specific better use the
                             % optional argument to \schemestart; else place
                             % it in the preamble
\setcompoundstyle{font=\scriptsize}
\schemestart
\chemfig{[:-30]*6(-=-(-[,1.2]BF{_3^-}K^+)=-=)}
\arrow{%
  ->[\footnotesize \normal-Bu$_4$N$^+$Br$^-$]%
    [\footnotesize THF, rt, 3--5\,min]}
\chemfig{[:-30]*6(-=-(-[,1.2]BF{_3^-}\text{\normal-}Bu_4N^+)=-=)}
\schemestop
\setcompoundstyle{}% default

\end{document}
```

[image]